# Qual é a relação da Lei de Conway com os sistemas de software?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, projeto-de-software

Estava lendo sobre a [lei de Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law). Entretanto, ainda não consegui compreender ela e sua relação com a estrutura dos sistemas.

O enunciado da lei é o seguinte:

> Any organization that designs a system (defined broadly) will produce a design whose structure is a copy of the organization's communication structure.

O ponto que cita que o designer do sistema reflete a estrutura de comunicação da organização que me deixou confuso.

## Dúvidas

1. Como a estrutura de comunicação de uma organização pode influencia na
   estrutura de um projeto de sistema, de acordo com a lei?
2. Que tipos de impactos uma comunicação ruim
   na organização podem causar nos processos e nos projetos de sistemas
   de software?

Comment: Não sei se existe algum grande artigo que aborde isso em detalhes mas gosto das explicações do Elemar Jr. https://www.eximia.co/pt/2019/08/21/conways-law/

Answer (score -4):

Por exemplo, se a empresa separa as equipes de desenvolvimento por módulos do sistema, empiricamente serão gerados estruturas de codificação que refletem esse modelo de trabalho.

No fim das contas você terá um conjunto de classes utilizados pelo time do módulo 01 e outro conjunto de classes utilizados pelo time que manipula o módulo 02.

Isso se dá muito para evitar conflitos e alterações redundantes, mas acaba gerando mais problemas do que soluções.

O melhor para desenvolvimento de soluções de software é criar um modelo de comunicação e fluxo de trabalho que permita a construção das soluções comuns em conjunto e a socialização do conhecimento referente a melhorias nas mesmas.

Answer (score -4):

A Lei de Conway destaca a importância da comunicação eficaz e colaboração entre as equipes para evitar fragmentação e desalinhamento na arquitetura do software. Muitas vezes, as organizações procuram estruturar suas equipes e processos de desenvolvimento de software de maneira que promova a coesão e a integração, favorecendo a criação de sistemas mais coesos e eficientes.
Por exemplo, se uma empresa tem equipes separadas para o frontend e o backend do desenvolvimento de software, é provável que o software resultante seja dividido em camadas correspondentes a essas especializações. Da mesma forma, se diferentes equipes estão localizadas em locais geográficos diferentes, o software pode refletir essa separação geográfica.